# Azure notif Hub number of tags Limit

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, azure-notificationhub

I have 1 million user in my app, i'm using Azure notification service.

i would like to set a unique tag(email address for example) for every user

Q1 : can i add 1 million tag ?
Q2 : is there any limits for tags numbers?

(i have already searched in the official docs and forums ? Nothing found )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag limits are applied per-registration, and you'll get an HTTP400 if you try to create a registration that exceeds the limit. I'll refrain from putting the limit here in case we want to increase it in the future.

Your scenario is definitely supported. Thanks for your patronage.